# jQuery .on() sometimes works, sometimes not

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

I have weird problem. At first I didn't want to use .on() method because I couldn't get it to work at all, so I used .live().

Now, I'm writing a new jQuery script and I used .on() heavily and it works. Until now.

jQuery code:

```
   $('#artistList a').on('click',function(e){
    console.log($(this).parent().text());
    e.preventDefault();
   });
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="artistList">
 <div class="artist"><a class="delete" href="#"></a>Psy</div>
 <div class="artist"><a class="delete" href="#"></a>Fernanda Martins</div>
 <div class="artist"><a class="delete" href="#"></a>DJ Nreal</div>
</div>
```

Also tried this methods:

```
   $('#artistList>a').on('click',function(e){
   $('.delete').on('click',function(e){
```

No luck. What am I missing?

This is the only part that doesn't work

I have read the documentation about .on() and based on that, this should work.
Also, I'm using the latest jQuery, (jquery-1.8.3.min.js).

**EDIT**

`<a>` elements have a `width: 15px` and `height: 15px` in CSS, so they are visible.

Comment: `on` is not like `live`. `on` needs to be delegated to have the same affect.

Comment: So it's better to use .delegate() in this manner?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to work like `live` you need to delegate the handler to a higher level element.

```
 $('body').on('click','#artistlist a', function(e) {
     // note the change to the selector to reflect your actual mark up
     // handler body
 });
```

Using this form of [on](http://api.jquery.com/on) is required if the elements to which the handler should apply are added dynamically after the page is initially loaded.  Note also that the handlers should be applied after the DOM is loaded either by placing scripts just before the end of the body element or using the `ready` event handler, `$(function() { ... });`

If a handler sometimes works and sometimes doesn't it's likely a race condition on page load between the elements being loaded into the DOM and the script being invoked. This is usually a sign that you've omitted adding the handlers inside the ready event handler.

Answer (score 4):

Your links (`<a>` elements) are empty here, so they obviously fail to catch `click` event. I suppose you forgot to move those `Psy`, `Fernanda Martins` etc. *inside* `<a href="..."></a>`.

Also, only the second selector will actually collect these links (as all they have class `delete` on them). The first one - `'#artistList>a'` - tries to find the anchors that are *direct* descendants of the element with `artistList` id. But it's destined to fail in this noble quest, because there's another layer separating them - `<div class="artist">`. So the rule should probably be something like `'#artistList a'`.

Comment: I just tried to add this two: _&nbsp;_ and _aa_ into <a></a>, no luck, <a> elements still don't catch click event. About the second selector, this was my typo, I should add one more >div in there. Let me just say, that this worked perfectly with .live().

Comment: Honestly speaking, that doesn't make any sense - unless these elements are added to DOM _after_ the lines that assign click handler to them are invoked. What happens if you use this form: `$('body').on('click', '#artistList a', function() {...})`?

Comment: Nope, the lines are there before `$(document).ready()` fires. I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12950226/777700 It's similar to your suggestion and it works, even with nothing in between `<a></a>`.